# Why does VoiceOver iOS revert the cursor position after tabbing away from an input field?

Tags: html, ios, safari, wai-aria, screen-readers

While testing VoiceOver for iOS within an @ionic/angular cordova app, I encountered the following issue:

I have two elements on a page. One is an `h1` with a tabindex of `0`. The other is a plain `<input>`.

1. I enter into 'edit mode' on the input field (double tap with VoiceOver on)
2. I reposition the screen reader focus to the `h1`
3. I double tap the `h1`

I would expect at this point that the screen reader focus would remain on the `h1`. Instead, the focus shifts back to the `<input>`.

This can be reproduced by opening this [StackBlitz](https://screen-reader-focus.stackblitz.io) in Safari on iOS and following the above steps.

Notes:

- the tabindex of 0 on the `h1` is to facilitate focusing at the top of the page after a transition.
- this happens on non `h1` elements as well, this is just an example; it seems more related to the tabindex than anything